# Problem with update-alternatives: Trop de niveaux de liens symboliques

Tags: apt, update-alternatives

I was intstalling some stuff in the computer:

```
sudo apt install gettext intltool python3-gi python3-cairo python3-distutils python3-dbus python3-xdg libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-bin gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gtk-update-icon-cache
# and for documentation
sudo apt install itstool yelp
```

And also hamster-time-tracker.

and now when i try to do "apt upgrade" i have this error:

```
listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  libodbc1
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 1 non mis à jour.
4 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] o
Paramétrage de automake (1:1.16.1-4ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: erreur: analyse impossible du fichier « /bin/javac »: Trop de niveaux de liens symboliques
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet automake (--configure) :
 installed automake package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Paramétrage de google-chrome-stable (87.0.4280.141-1) ...
update-alternatives: erreur: analyse impossible du fichier « /bin/javac »: Trop de niveaux de liens symboliques
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet google-chrome-stable (--configure) :
 installed google-chrome-stable package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Paramétrage de firefox (84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: erreur: analyse impossible du fichier « /bin/javac »: Trop de niveaux de liens symboliques
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet firefox (--configure) :
 installed firefox package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de intltool :
 intltool dépend de automake | automaken ; cependant :
 Le paquet automake n'est pas encore configuré.
  Le paquet automaken n'est pas installé.
  Le paquet automake qui fournit automaken n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet intltool (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 automake
 google-chrome-stable
 firefox
 intltool
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If i chek the javac link i have this:

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 janv.  7 12:32  javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac`

If i check /etc/alternatives/javac i have this:

`lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  10 janv.  7 13:35 javac -> /bin/javac`

I have the impression that it should point to /usr/bin/javac coz the rest of links points to /usr/ folders and i think because of that it creates a infinite loop. But i dont know how to change that. And also i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

I've deleted it the symbolic links and i've installed new openjdk version. That i've change it with update-alternatives. That has creates the propert links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Here are a few ideas for you to try...

- Have you tried running
  `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
  This will rebuild the package database.
- You can also try to force any failed installation
  `sudo apt-get install -f`
- Of course you can also remove any of the offending packages to see if that resolves the problem
  `sudo apt remove <packagename>`

Hope that helps.